# Error :current provider doesn't support subscriptions : using ganache, web3 1.0.0

Tags: web3js, events

how to solve the error :

> The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider at
>   Subscription.subscribe

while using web3 1.0.0 and ganche

Comment: see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/34840/53423 for a solution